# Type Error For positional Argument - Inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I'm getting type error for positional Argument though I have passed exactly 4 arguments

```
class Employee:

    raise_amount =1.10

    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first=first
        self.last=last
        self.pay=pay
        self.email=first+'.'+last+'@company.com'

    def get_fullname(self):
        return self.first + self.last

    def apply_raise(self):
         return self.pay *self.raise_amount



class Developer(Employee):
    def __int__(self,first,last,pay,prog_lang):
        super().__init__(first,last,pay)
        self.prog_lang = prog_lang




d1 = Developer('Vidit','Shah',1000,'Python')

print(d1.prog_lang)
```

Error Statemment :

`d1 = Developer('Vidit','Shah',1000,'Python')
TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given`

I checked my indentation it seems fine to me.
Please guide me

Comment: ``def __int__`` should be ``def __init__`` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misspelled `__init__`. The second `i` is missing - `__int__`. Took me a while :)

Answer (score 1):

`Developer` defines `__int__` not `__init__`, so `Developer` inherits `Employee.__init__`.